# Do these module theorems in algebra have a right version?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

I know the following theorems:

(1) Let $D$ be a skew field and $R= M_n(D)$. Then $R$ is simple, left semisimple, left Artinian and left Noetherian. Moreover, $R$ has a unique (up to isomorphism) simple left faithful submodule $M$ such that $R \cong M \oplus \dots \oplus M$ where $R$ is considered to be the regular left $R$-module.

(2) The finite direct product of left semisimple rings is left semisimple.

(3) Let $R$ be a left semisimple ring. Then

$$R \cong M_{n_1}(D_1) \times \dots M_{n_k}(D_k)$$

for skew fields $D_1, \dots, D_k$ and $n_1, \dots, n_k \geq 1$. The number $k$ and the pairs $(n_i, D_i)$ are uniquely determined (up to permutation).

**Do these theorems have a right version?** I.e. if I replace the word left to right in these theorems, are these theorems true? I guess the answer is an obvious yes, but I want a quick sanity check. The same proofs with modifications seem to apply.

I'm asking this because I am asked to prove that a ring $R$ is left semisimple if and only if the ring is right semisimple.

If the answer to my first question is yes, then we can argue as follows:

Assume $R$ is left semisimple. Then by $(3)$ $R$ is a product of matrix rings over skew fields. By the right versions of $(1),(2)$, $R$ is also right semisimple.

Conversely is done in the same way: if $R$ is right semisimple, then by the right version of $(3)$ $R$ is a product of matrix rings over skew fields. By $(1)$ and $(2)$, $R$ is left semisimple.

**Is all of the above correct?**

Comment: Most texts on semisimple rings immediately note that the concept turns out to be left-right symmetric. I wonder which text you are using that does not adequately do this?

Comment: Lam's book "A first course in noncommutative rings"

Comment: Seems you haven't read far enough.  Semisimple rings are defined on page 27, and then seven pages later Corollary 3.7 the author makes the comment I mentioned.

Comment: That' seven pages further. The point of my post is exactly the proof of this very fact.

Comment: OK, when I asked "what book are you reading that doesn't prove the notion is left-right symmetric" you should not have responded with a book that you knew already did just that...  It doesn't seem very advisable to use these three theorems to prove the notion is symmetric when you can deduce symmetry independently and then have these three theorems as a corollary.

Comment: @rschwieb You need a right version of Wedderburn's theorem before you can prove that left semisimple = right semisimple, right? And such a right version is obtained by adapting the proofs to get the left version or using the opposite ring as in the answer below?

Comment: No, I don't think you need two versions of Wedderburn's theorem.  I think there are a few ways authors deduce symmetry from a "one-sided" version such as what Eric Wofsey does below, and I think Isaacs does something slightly different in *Algebra: a graduate course*.

Comment: Okay, but how does Lam do it? In corollary 3.7, he says a left semisimple ring is right semisimple. What results does he use to conclude this? At the least he uses Wedderburn's Artin left version and that the product of finitely many right semisimple rings is right semisimple and that a matrix ring is right semisimple. For the converse, we need the dual statements I believe, and these are nowhere to be found in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, everything works if you replace "left" with "right".  In fact, instead of modifying the proofs, you can *deduce* the right cases from the left cases as follows.  Given a ring $R$, let $R^{op}$ be $R$ but with the order of multiplication flipped.  Note that a right $R$-module is the same thing as a left $R^{op}$-module.  So, $R$ is right semisimple, Noetherian, etc. iff $R^{op}$ is left semisimple, Noetherian, etc.  Moreover, if $D$ is a skew field, then so is $D^{op}$, and $M_n(D)^{op}\cong M_n(D^{op})$ by the transpose map.

So, if you apply the theorems to $R^{op}$ instead of to $R$ (and similarly with all the skew fields), you just get the theorems for $R$ but with "left" replaced by "right" everywhere.

Comment: On the other hand, one *cannot* deduce from the fact that a ring is right Noetherian that it's also left Noetherian (the same for other properties). The property of being semisimple is special: indeed a ring is left semisimple if and only if it is right semisimple (because of Wedderburn-Artin).